# Why is my camera irregular and how do I fix it

Tags: rendering, camera

[image: width demonstration]
I need it to match the grid's width for a shot.
I don't see anything wrong with the render:
[image: Render settings snapshot]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "irregular"...? If you want no perspective, set the camera type to *ortho*.

Answer (score 1):

In the Object Properties, under Transform, make sure Location X is set to 0.